# Checking for Jakarta Validation annotation during compilation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, annotations

If I declare a method that uses a validation annotation on its parameter, for instance:

```
public void myMethod(@NonNull String s){}
```

I would like Eclipse to mark

```
myMethod(null);
```

as a compilation error.

Is it doable ? (After comment it seems there's a specific configuration in Eclipse for null checking, but what about the others ?)

I added dependencies to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator and jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api.

I enabled Annotation Processing (had to add specific configuration on the project, I did not find the option for Java Compiler at the Workspace level)
I added both jars in the Factory Path of the annotation processor

Still nothing happens.
Am I missing something ? Is it even possible ?

Or should these be considered just declarative, (and in this case do I even need to import the hibernate-validator implementation ?)

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Errors/Warning_, in the section _Null analysis_, you have to check the checkbox _Enable annotation-based null analysis_. If you use other null annotations than `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.*` you have to configure these as well (click the link _Configure..._ provided at the checkbox _Use default annotations for null specifications_).

Comment: Thanks it seems Eclipse has a specific configuration for null test, where I could add the jakarta annotation, but what about the other annotations like @Positive ?

Comment: The Jakarta validation annotation `@Positive` is for checking values at run time ([`@Retention(RUNTIME)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api/3.0.2/jakarta/validation/constraints/Positive.html)), not at compile time, right?

Comment: The RetentionPolicy indicates it's available at runtime, but is it an indication that it should be used only at runtime ?

Comment: To my understanding, the Jakarta validation framework is to be used at run time only. For static code analysis, it would lead to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem): only very simple cases can be covered, as such checks can become infinitely complex depending on the code to be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the API is not meant for that. However Eclipse can naturally handle some annotations related to null values.

There is no general preferences for this but annotation handling can be set at the project level.
Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Annotations Processing
Enable project specific settings
Enable annotation processing

The severity level needs to be set, this one can be done at General level instead of project.
Preferences > Compiler > Errors/Warning
In the "Null analysis" section check "Enable annotation-based null analysis"
The "Use default annotations for null specifications" has a "Configure" button.

Here are the handled annotations: @Nullable @NonNull @NonNullByDefault. These are Eclipse annotation but you can add other annotations to be handled for the same meaning.

However, this is the only available, there is no specific configuration that would configure the use of @Positive or other jakarta annotations.
You then need to define

Within the Annotations Processing section, there is Factory Path subsection to define other annotation processor than the default one, but adding hibernate validator here had no effect for me. Probably because there is no configuration available to set a severity on these annotation violations.

Note: Having an error severity level on a @NonNull annotation would prevent tests (that would assertThrow an exception for instance) from compiling.